# ElasticSearch stored_fields java API

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene

I am trying to build ElasticSearch query using java API. This query uses stored_fields, can anyone please help me how to build stored_field query from java code.

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "stored_fields": [
    "f1",
    "f2",
    "f3",
    "f4"
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "compositeField1": {
            "query": "test123",
            "type": "boolean",
            "operator": "AND"
          }
        }
      }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_score": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What is your ElasticSearch version?

Comment: I am using ElasticSearch 5.2 version

Answer (score 1):

Code following

```
    SearchRequestBuilder srb = ....
    srb.setFrom(0).setSize(10).storedFields("f1", "f2", "f3", "f4");
    srb.addSort(SortBuilders.scoreSort());

    BoolQueryBuilder bqb = new BoolQueryBuilder();
    bqb.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("compositeField1", "test123")
            .operator(Operator.AND).type(MatchQuery.Type.BOOLEAN));
    srb.setQuery(bqb);
```

Note: ES set some default required parameters.